# Win32 vs Win32api

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I downloaded pywin32 (using pip), and want to use the win32api, however, the module doesn't exist. win32 exists and win32com exist, but not win32api. How can I access win32api(specifically I want to be able to access the GetVolumeInformation) function.

Comment: its `win32api` not `win32API`

Comment: sorry that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, win32api is part of win32, so I just changed the import to win32.win32api.